# Converting this ninject 1.0 code to ninject 2.0

Tags: ninject, ninject-2

I am trying to follow this tutorial http://damianm.com/tech/nhibernate-mvc-and-ninject/

but I am running into some problems and I believe they are related to changes that where made when they released 2.0

I never used ninject 1.0 and I been using ninject 2.0 for less then a week so I am finding it difficult to convert.

I think this

```
//1.0
    Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToProvider(new SessionFactoryProvider()).Using<SingletonBehavior>();
```

needs to be changed to

```
//2.0
      Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToProvider(new SessionFactoryProvider()).InSingletonScope();
```

this

```
//1.0
     Bind<ISession>().ToProvider(new SessionProvider()).Using<OnePerRequestBehavior>();
```

to

```
//2.0
    Bind<ISession>().ToProvider(new SessionProvider()).InRequestScope();
```

These ones I can't find what they would be

```
// 1.0 -SimpleProvider
public class SessionProvider : SimpleProvider<ISession>
public class SessionFactoryProvider : SimpleProvider<ISessionFactory>
```

The above is what I identified so far a what needs to be converted.

I also see this in one of his repository classes

```
Bind<IRepository<Post>>().To<Repository<Post>>();
```

I don't know what really that is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleProvider changed to Provider

```
public class SessionProvider : Provider<ISession>
public class SessionFactoryProvider : Provider<ISessionFactory>
```

Comment: thanks then I got the right ones. I am wondering do you know if InRequestScope(); will automatically close things like nhibernate sessions?

Comment: The latest version of Ninject changed that the default beahvior is to immendiately release and dispose objects InRequestScope. To close the transaction you either have to do this in the dispose of the session or in a deactivation action.

Comment: So then my sessions are closing as they are since they are in the requestscope. I just have to worry about closing the transactions then? What is a deactivation action. I was thinking when I do a commit I just use a using statement and let it close itself.